# Java: How to format double without leading 0? (.2 rather than 0.2)

Tags: java

I'm currently using `String.format("%.1f", number)` to format a double to have exactly 1 decimal number. However, they show up as `0.2` for instance. Is it possible to format it without the `0` so it looks like `.2`?

When I search for this, all I can find are solutions on how to add more leading 0's...

Comment: `substring` or `replace` should work?

Comment: `if(string.beginsWith("0."))  string = string.substring(1);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) :

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#.0"); // or the equivalent ".0"
System.out.println(formatter.format(0.564f));    // displays ".6"
System.out.println(formatter.format(12.546f));   // displays "12.5"
System.out.println(formatter.format(12f));       // displays "12.0"
```

In the format specifier, the use of `#` over `0` indicates that no digit is to be displayed in case the value is absent.

If you don't want to display trailing zeroes you will want to use `#.#` as the format specifier. The dot will not appear if there is no decimal part :

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
System.out.println(formatter.format(0.564f));    // displays ".6"
System.out.println(formatter.format(12.546f));   // displays "12.5"
System.out.println(formatter.format(12f));       // displays "12"
```

Noticed how the `0.564` was rounded up? If that's not to your taste, you can change the rounding algorithm used by using the  `DecimalFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode mode)` method. Use `RoundingMode.DOWN` if you want to simply truncate the extra digits.